# Specifying shape width generates error: The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save Excel diagrams as images.

With the whole code I call several workbooks, lookup all worksheets and save all diagrams.

The following code works with Excel 2007 and 2010 (but there is a horizontal and vertical line visible because of the + 4). If I change the `Round(shp.Width + 4, 0)` to `Round(shp.Width, 0)` I get the following error in 2010 (but not in 2007):

> Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>   The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type.

```
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)
Set shp = sht.Shapes(chrtName)

shp.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

Dim objChart As ChartObject
Set objChart = sht.ChartObjects.Add(200, 200, Round(shp.Width + 4, 0), Round(shp.Height + 4, 0))
objChart.Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
ActiveChart.Export Filename:=fullPath, Filtername:=Right(fullPath, 3)
objChart.Delete
```

How I can avoid using the +4?

I found the following:

> "The problem occurs whenever the default chart type is set to other chart types than the ones you are trying to create. For an example, if you try to create line chart and if the default chart in Excel is OHLC (Candlestick Stock Chart) then Excel will be fast to complain "The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type". The same occurs even if you try to create charts from VB.NET. Hence, first of all change the default chart type to some basic chart types like Line charts. The problem will be solved."
>   http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=204071

How can I do this with VBA?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same exception. I traced the problem to the save path.

If the save path is wrong, or the specified path does not exist, then this exception will be raised. Check to make sure that the path exists.

Answer (score 2):

Long time no answer.

You need to do two things. First, make sure no data is selected, or Excel may try to put it into the chart you're creating.

Insert this block

```
Dim rngTmp as range
If Typename(Selection) = "Range" then
  Set rngTmp = selection
End If
With ActiveSheet
  .Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.Count - 1).Select
End With
```

before the line

```
Set objChart = sht.ChartObjects.Add(...)
```

and insert the following after the above line

```
ObjChart.Chart.ChartType = xlLine ' or another "safe" chart type
If Not rngTmp is Nothing then
  rngTmp.select
End If
```

Strictly speaking, if you are not adding data to the chart, you don't need to change the chart type, but for the sake of OCD, it's better to be complete.

Comment: @jon, how you can "select" a cell that does not exist?  The line .Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.Count + 1).Select throws an exception in my testing, which makes sense because row .Rows.Count + 1 does not exist.

Comment: The other answer, which uses `Shapes.AddChart2()` or `Shapes.AddChart()` in place of `ChartObjects.Add()`, is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`Set objChart = Worksheet.Shapes.AddChart2().Chart.Parent`

instead of

`Set objChart = Worksheet.ChartObjects.Add()`

The former function allows you to specify a basic chart type in the second argument.

Comment: Use `AddChart()` in place of `AddChart2()` for compatibility with Excel 2007 and 2010.